# Start-job for each computer in my csv

Tags: powershell, csv, automation, powershell-3.0

i'm looking for a way to start a new job for each computer in my csv, to launch parallel job on each of them.

I already have this

```
$job1 = Start-Job -Scriptblock {

$Csv = "C:\springfield\Citrix\CitrixComposants.csv"
$myservers = Import-Csv $Csv

Import-module C:\springfield\Citrix\CitrixDeploymentActivlanModule.ps1
Deploy-Citrix -servers $myservers[0].server -component $myservers[0].component

}
```

How can i get $job[n] as many as there are servers in my csv ?

I was thinking about something like this, but maybe there is a better way to achieve that.
My idea is to create a dynamic $job variable ($job1, $job2, $job3, $job[n]...)

```
$Csv = "C:\springfield\Citrix\CitrixComposants.csv"

for ($i=0;$i -lt $csv.count; $i++)
{

$job+"$i" = Start-Job -Scriptblock {

$Csv = "C:\springfield\Citrix\CitrixComposants.csv"
$myservers = Import-Csv $Csv

Import-module C:\springfield\Citrix\CitrixDeploymentActivlanModule.ps1
Deploy-Citrix -servers $myservers[$i].server -component $myservers[$i].component

}

}
```

I also would like when a job finishes it shows me it's completed, how can i get that?

I'm using powershell v4.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, currently you are running one job for all the servers. Or you would be if you weren't specifying $Myservers[0].

If any results are returned you can see the results by using receive-job. I would think the results would contain output returned from each server, assuming you removed $myservers[0] and that deploy-citrix cmdlet accepts an array. If you just want to check the status you can use get-job.

If you wanted to instead start a job for each server it should look more like this:

```
$Csv = "C:\springfield\Citrix\CitrixComposants.csv"
$myservers = Import-Csv $Csv

Foreach ($Server in $MyServers)
{
    $SrvName = $Server.Server
    $Component = $Server.Component
    Start-Job -ArgumentList $SrvName,$Component -Scriptblock {
    Param ($SrvName,$Component)
    Import-module C:\springfield\Citrix\CitrixDeploymentActivlanModule.ps1
    Deploy-Citrix -servers $Srvname -component $component
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work... Powershell doesn't recognize $Server.Server and $Server.component, because it's inside Start-Job -Scriptblock :(

Comment: I edited the answer...forgot that jobs need an argument list...can you try that?